# Make stripe "data-amount" use a dynamic with a variable

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

I am in need of getting my script checkout to use my `var $priceCheckout = $('#priceCheckout');` for the checkout price value.

I have tried to replace the data-amount="2000" with `data-amount= $priceCheckout;` without any luck. So to be cleare!

It needs to take my $priceCheckout and get it placede at data-amount so that the value of $priceCheckout will be the checkout price!

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="Personal key"
    data-amount= ???
    data-name="Elo Calculator"
    data-description="Checkout price"
    data-image="/128x128.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

This is my script for it.

```
$(function () {
            // Store references to frequently used elements - for speed.
            var $divFrom = $('#division-from');
            var $divTo = $('#division-to');
            var $tierFrom = $('#tier-from');
            var $tierTo = $('#tier-to');

            var $price = $('#price');
            var $priceCheckout = $('#priceCheckout');

            // Select price calculation callback
            $(document).on('change', '.price-modifier', function () {
                var divFrom = $divFrom.val();
                var divTo = $divTo.val();
                var tierFrom = $tierFrom.val();
                var tierTo = $tierTo.val();

                // Error handling
                var errors = validatePriceModifiers(divFrom, tierFrom, divTo, tierTo);
                if (errors.length === 0) {
                    // No errors
                    var price = getPrice(divFrom, tierFrom, divTo, tierTo);
                    $price.html(price + ' €' + '<br /> <br />' + '<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-info">Buy</button>');
                    $priceCheckout.html(price);
                } else {
                    // Display errors
                    $price.empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                        $price.append($('<p>').html(errors[i].message));
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I am unsure what it is exactly you are asking, could you try to clarify your question and fix any spelling/language mistakes?

Comment: I'm not good at english hmm. It's because that i have a price caluclator where if you select 1 thing it gives 1 price and if you select another it gives another price. I need it to be so that the price it is placede it my  data-amount for checkout. I have a variable that is callede $priceCheckout it has all my prices. And it's that's price i need it to add to  data-amount = ""

Comment: `$('.stripe-button').attr('data-amount', $priceCheckout);`  Now in your code, `$priceCheckout` isn't a value but a jq object. Anyway, i don't see purpose of it. You should try at least to provide MCVE

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a Checkout [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) for this.

Here is a simple fiddle showing how to use Checkout with a user-specified amount: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/g2ufa8xr/

You can use the same logic to plug in your own value as the `amount` parameter in the call to `handler.open()`.

Comment: Can you try set it with my #priceCheckout ? I can't make it work :( Would be really nice. This is what i use to calculate price: var $priceCheckout = $('#priceCheckout'); .

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that `data-amount` is a attribute to the HTML script tag. It is *not* a JavaScript variable, and you can *not* directly assign one to it in the HTML markup (like `<element attribute=variable-name>`).

However, you can assign a value to it using JavaScript like this:

```
$('.stripe-button').attr('data-amount', $priceCheckout);
```

That code will change the attribute `data-amount` of any HTMl element with the class `stripe-button` to the value the variable `$priceCheckout` has when the code runs.

So when do you want to run it? You need to run it after the `$priceCheckout` is set to the variable (and you need to run it again to update if the price changes). But you need to run it before whatever code that uses the value runs.

Comment: Then you are probably setting it at the wrong time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Stripe's Custom Checkouts. Although, I found an easier way to do this through jQuery simply by remounting the script with the changed variable each time they increase the quantity:

```
var $priceCheckout = $('#priceCheckout');

$("#stripe-form").html(
  '<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="pk_test_123123123123" data-amount="' +
    $priceCheckout.replace(".", "") +
    '" data-zip-code="true" data-currency="usd" data-billing-address="true" data-shipping-address="true" data-name="Company Name" data-description="Product Name" data-image="https://image" data-locale="auto"></script>'
);
```