# Setting up custom stripe checkout using the default stripe form

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

So, I've been trying to get the custom stripe checkout form for me. I wasn't able to use the simple version as I need to be able to change the amount to be paid and the description for each and every purchase where the standard stripe checkout form has only set values for these two variables that cannot be changed. I do not, however, want to use a custom form, I simply want to checkout using the standard form. My issue is trying to send this data to the server, I have tried numerous different methods but I just can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
            <p><input id="buy-submit-button" class="button" type="submit" value="チェックアウト"></input></p>

            <script> 
            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: 'pk_test_g6do5S237ekq10r65BnxO6S0',
                locale: 'auto',
                token: function(token) {

                        //don't know what needs to go here

                }
            });

                document.getElementById("buy-submit-button").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    var totalCost = 0; 
                    var totalCartLoad = ""; 
                    totalCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCartPrice'); 
                    totalCartLoad = localStorage.getItem('whatsInCart'); 
                    totalCartLoad = totalCartLoad.replace('undefined',''); 

                    // Open Checkout with further options:
                    handler.open({
                        name: "チェックアウト",
                        description: totalCartLoad,
                        shippingAddress: true,
                        billingAddress: true,
                        zipCode: true,
                        allowRememberMe: true,
                        currency: 'JPY',
                        amount: totalCost

                    });
                    e.preventDefault();

                }, 500);

            });

            // Close Checkout on page navigation:
            window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
                handler.close();
            });
            </script>
```

So I'll just reiterate that again. All I want to do is use stripes default form that pops up when you press the button and then have it submitted to the server, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make stripe "data-amount" use a dynamic with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521404/make-stripe-data-amount-use-a-dynamic-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question using the answer provided to another question here: [make-stripe-data-amount-use-a-dynamic-with-a-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521404/make-stripe-data-amount-use-a-dynamic-with-a-variable)